# Django and Apache configuration, page not loading

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

Disclaimer: I know this issue has been addressed multiple times but I'm experiencing different errors than the other posted questions.

I have a Django app which I am trying to get configured with Apache running on the web. I go to load some.example.com and absolutely nothing shows up in the browser. Whenever I restart the Apache server the following appears in the error log

```
RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `example.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

**Edit**: looking at the error logs in my other working Django apps I am seeing the same `RSA server...` error, so I don't think this is what is causing the error.

I've done this before multiple times, I even documented my process so I wouldn't run into the same errors. My documented process has worked in the past and I currently have multiple Django apps running on my server. In the past I've received errors like "can't write to database" or "can't server static files", but I've never seen a blank screen before. I even have `DEBUG = True` in my Django settings file.

I mostly follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](http://16bpp.net/pages/how-to-deploy-a-django-app-with-apache) tutorial. Steps:

1. Create Django app (running built-in server works, everything loads perfectly)
2. Create virtual environment, install Django inside
3. create /etc/apache2/sites-available/some.example.com
4. Create symlink to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/some.example.com
5. Edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/some.example.com as below
6. Run the following commands

   ```
   chown -R username:www-data some.example.com
   chmod 775 some.example.com
   chmod 664 some.example.com/db.sqlite3
   ```

I am using Django 1.7 and Apache 2.2.22.

wsgi.py

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/srv/www/some.example.com/heartstudyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "heartstudy.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/some.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName some.example.com
    ServerAlias some.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/some.example.com

    Alias /static /srv/www/some.example.com/static
    <Directory /srv/www/some.example.com/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/some.example.com/heartstudy>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess heartstudy python-path=/srv/www/some.example.com:/srv/www/some.example.com/heartstudyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup heartstudy
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/wwwsomeexample.com/heartstudy/wsgi.py
 </VirtualHost>

 NameVirtualHost *:443
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/sslkey/_.example.com/_.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sslkey/_.example.com/_.example.com.key

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName some.example.com
    ServerAlias some.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/some.example.com

    WSGIProcessGroup heartstudy
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/some.example.com/heartstudy/wsgi.py

    Alias /static /srv/www/some.example.com/static
    <Directory /srv/www/some.example.com/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/some.example.com/heartstudy>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /srv/www/some.example.com/apache_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/www/some.example.com'
MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

SECRET_KEY = 'some_key'

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['some.example.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'tweets',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'heartstudy.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'heartstudy.wsgi.application'

LOGIN_URL = '/tweets/login/'
SITE_ID = 3

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = (
    MEDIA_PATH,
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
```

Comment: The error has very little to do with django. This is Apache telling you that example.com is not the same as some.example.com.

Comment: I can't figure out where the error is coming from. I don't see a reference to example.com anywhere without the some.

Comment: Your certificate contains the domain it is supposed to protect. This error tells you that the domain embedded in the certificate is different from the one in your apache config. You can see your certificate info by doing openssl x509 -in your-certificate.pem -text

Comment: Thanks @MadWombat. I'm still confused as to why this works for other sites but not this one, I have similar Apache configs for two other Django apps.

Comment: Looking at the error logs for the working sites shows the same `RSA server...` error so I'm doubting that this is what is causing the errors.

Comment: Dude. I don't know what your setup looks like. I am telling you that this error is reported when the domain name in your certificate is different from domain name in your apache config ServerName directive. You can google the error and see this answer in dozens of places.

Comment: @MadWombat Sorry, wasn't trying to come off as harsh :) I appreciate your help. You pointed out that the above error has little to do with Django and I wanted to point out that I think the error also has little to do with the issues I'm trying to solve, as similar errors are present in working app.

Comment: I see. OK, the blank page problem might indicate that something makes your app crash before it is fully loaded or it crashes while trying to render the error page (don't laugh, it happened to me on several occasions). Try to run the app using manage.py runserver command and see if it loads and you can see your page.

Comment: I can run the server locally just fine, app works and loads as expected.

Comment: And you are not getting anything interesting in /srv/www/some.example.com/apache_error.log Besides the certificate error.

Comment: No errors. Only get the certificate error when rebooting Apache.

Comment: I am guessing, your app doesn't load, so it is unable to provide you with any real errors. Look into the basics, do you have the right database config, does everything have right permissions etc. Can you run the app on the same server in the same location as your apache? Does apache user have all the required permissions?

Comment: I'll go back through all of that stuff again. Thanks for the help and suggestions @madwombat